# Count records from two tables grouped by one field

Tags: mysql, count, records

I have 2 tables:

1. doctorreports with fields:

   - DoctorRepID
   - RepName
   - DoctorName
   - DateAdded
2. hospitals with fields:

   - HospitalID
   - RepName
   - HospitalName
   - DoctorName
   - DateAdded

I need to count the records added by each RepName in doctorreports & hospitals with the DateAdded.

I need it to appear like this:

```
RepName | DoctorReportsCount | HospitalsReportsCount | DateAdded
        |                    |                       |
  John  |          15        |          12           | 9/4/2012
```

RepName in doctorsreports table equal RepName in hospitals table.

@bluefeet This is partially what I need, but can we unify the DateAdded field to be if the RepName hasn't added any records in this date then the DateAdded = 0. For example :

```
RepName | DoctorReportsCount | HospitalsReportsCount | DateAdded
        |                    |                       |
  John  |          15        |          12           | 9/4/2012
  Ann   |          9         |           0           | 9/2/2012
Tamer   |          0         |           12          | 9/1/2012
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to do this:

<strike>`select d.RepName,
      count(d.RepName) DoctorReportsCount,
      count(h.RepName) HospitalsReportsCount,
      d.DateAdded
    from doctorreports d
    inner join hospitals h
      on d.RepName = h.RepName
    group by d.RepName, d.DateAdded`</strike>

edit:

<strike>`select *
    from
    (
      select d.RepName,
          count(d.RepName) DoctorReportsCount
        , d.dateadded
      from doctorreports d
      group by d.RepName, d.dateadded
    ) d
    left join
    (
      select h.RepName,
        count(h.RepName) HospitalsReportsCount
      , h.dateadded hDateadded
      from hospitals h
      group by h.RepName, h.dateadded
    )h
      on d.RepName = h.RepName`</strike>

## see [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88e2e/4)

edit #2, if you want to return data for days that are missing, then I would advise creating a table to contain calendar dates, then you can return data for days that are missing. The following should return what you are looking for.  Be advised, I created a calendar table for this query:

```
select COALESCE(d.drep, '') repname,
  COALESCE(d.DCount, 0) DoctorReportsCount,
  COALESCE(h.HCount, 0) HospitalsReportsCount,
  c.dt Dateadded
from calendar c
left join
(
  select repname drep,
    count(repname) DCount,
    dateadded ddate
  from doctorreports
  group by repname, dateadded
) d
  on c.dt = d.ddate
left join
(
  select repname hrep,
    count(repname) HCount,
    dateadded hdate
  from hospitals
  group by repname, dateadded
) h
  on c.dt = h.hdate
  and d.drep = h.hrep
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91643/37)

If you don't care about the other dates, then this is how you would do it without a `date` table:

```
select COALESCE(d.RepName, '') repname,
  COALESCE(d.DoctorReportsCount, 0) DoctorReportsCount,
  COALESCE(h.HospitalsReportsCount, 0) HospitalsReportsCount,
  COALESCE(p.PharmacyReportsCount, 0) PharmacyReportsCount,
  d.dateadded Dateadded
from
(
  select d.RepName,
      count(d.RepName) DoctorReportsCount
    , d.dateadded
  from doctorreports d
  group by d.RepName, d.dateadded
) d
left join
(
  select h.RepName,
    count(h.RepName) HospitalsReportsCount
  , h.dateadded hDateadded
  from hospitals h
  group by h.RepName, h.dateadded
)h
  on d.RepName = h.RepName
  and d.dateadded = h.hDateadded
left join
(
  select p.RepName,
    count(p.RepName) PharmacyReportsCount
  , p.dateadded hDateadded
  from PharmacyReports p
  group by p.RepName, p.dateadded
)p
  on d.RepName = p.RepName
  and d.dateadded = p.hDateadded
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91643/40)

Comment: yes but the output of your query is giving always DoctorReportsCount = HospitalsReportsCount for any RepName.

Comment: For example if a RepName didn't add reports on date 9/4/2012 it counts 0

Comment: @TamerSherif you should post some sample data for both tables, it is helpful it writing the queries.  Even better create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the table structures and some data.

Comment: @TamerSherif please see my edit.  If this is not the result that you want, please edit your OP and post the expected result based on the sample data you have provided.

Comment: @bluefleet please check the original post

Comment: @bluefleet Thank you very much i appreciate your PROFESSIONAL support

Comment: @bluefleet Last question please, If i have a 3rd table with same fields called PharmacyReports i need count the records as well to be PharmacyReportsCount.What should be the query?

Comment: @TamerSherif you would model it after the other one and just join to it, see my edit with the other table added

Comment: @bluefleet i have found a problem if the value in DoctorReportsCount = 0 the whole record doesn't exist.I added 2 records in HospitalsReportsCount but not shown in the results.Please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4ef92/1

Comment: @TamerSherif that is why I said if you want to include dates that do not exist, you have to use a `date` table, see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4ef92/4

Comment: @bluefleet Yes i see, but why in your example the 1st three rows are blank although there's a RepName called "Tamer" added 2 records in hospitals?

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL statement should bring the results you want:

```
SELECT 
    RepName,
    SUM(DoctorReports) AS DoctorReportsCount,
    SUM(HospitalReports) AS HospitalReportsCount,
    DateAdded
FROM (
    (SELECT RepName, COUNT(*) AS DoctorReports, 0 AS HospitalReports, DateAdded
     FROM doctorreports
     GROUP BY RepName, DateAdded)
    UNION
    (SELECT RepName, 0 AS DoctorReports, COUNT(*) AS HospitalReports, DateAdded
     FROM hospitals
     GROUP BY RepName, DateAdded)
) AS temp
GROUP BY
    RepName, DateAdded
ORDER BY
    RepName, DateAdded;
```

Comment: If i have a 3rd table with same fields called PharmacyReports i need count the records as well to be PharmacyReportsCount.What should be the query?